# Process Builder don't run action on a particular day

Tags: process-builder

I have a process builder setup.

I want to send an E-mail twice a day for the first three days.

I call an apex class every 12 hours which does this 6 times.

However, I don't want to call this apex code on Sunday.

I could have a check to not send an E-mail on Sunday. However, this would only send the E-mails for two days, if the processes is started on Saturday. So four times instead of 6.

Is there a way around this?

[image]

Comment: Could you test Today() in the Condition and check if it is Sunday?

Comment: Hi, I made a work around. When a new lead record is created, set a default value of a custom field to that day. Then check what day it was crated and run predefined actions.